# Default Page will not change

Tags: android, android-manifest

My home page needs to show two buttons: login & register. The page Login Activity with both buttons should appear first, but only the register screen comes up.

I am very new to coding. So, please be nice :( I've been stuck on this for days.

Below is the AndroidManifest.xml. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.thrd">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserAreaActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Include your home page's class file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You manifest file is ok. Probably you have some logical errors in your code. In LoginActivity. So it launches RegisterActivity (probably in onCreate), instead of showing itself.

Comment: You should write it as a comment not as an answer.

Comment: I never consider answer saying "Probably"

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @JFran No problem )